# Check if text starts with characters followed by numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to set a variable to certain values based on what a searchtext starts with.

What I currently have:

```
var action;

switch (searchText.substr(0, 3).toUpperCase()) {

    case 'ABC':
        action = 'foo';
    break;

    case 'CDE':
        action = 'bar';
    break;

}
```

This works. But I would like to extend it so that instead of only checking if the text startswith `ABC` it should be `ABC` + at least two numbers, like `ABC12`. How would I make a regular expression inside my switch case that validates against that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed regexes in a switch statement by using `switch(true)` in combination with `regex.test`:

```
switch(true) {

    case /^ABC\d\d/g.test(searchText):
        action = 'foo';
    break;

    case /^XYZ$/.test(searchText):
        action = 'bar';
    break;
}
```

Although I'd personally prefer a table-driven approach:

```
function firstMatch(text, mapping) {
    for(var i = 0; i < mapping.length; i++)
        if(mapping[i][0].test(text))
            return mapping[i][1];
}

actions = [
    [/^ABC\d\d/g, 'foo'],
    [/^XYZ\d\d/g, 'bar'],
]


action = firstMatch(searchText, actions)
```

Comment: @Johan: no. `/^ABC\d\d/.test(x)` returns true for "ABC" and _at least_ two numbers (it just ignores the rest).

Answer (score 2):

```
searchText.toUpperCase().match(/^ABC\d{2,}$/)
```

it will return not `null` in case if the string starts with `ABC` and contains at least 2 digits

Comment: You'd also want to `toUpperCase()` the string to scan or use case insensitive flag to match the behaviour of the OP's original code.

Comment: The `$` is probably unwanted as we're only looking at what the text starts with.

Comment: @MikeM: well, we're here not to solve other people's problems but to give hints

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to make a switch case for not null? Similar to `switch(true)` for booleans